# How to order the keys that reside in a map in a certain order using Scala?

Tags: scala

Follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44230560/2777965).

How to reorder

```
List(Map(d -> 4, a -> 12, c -> 30, b -> 2), Map(d -> 80, a -> 22, c -> 6666, b -> 442))
```

to

```
List(Map(d -> 4, b -> 2, a -> 12, c -> 30), Map(d -> 80, b -> 442, a -> 22, c -> 6666))
```

using Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Map` is usually an unordered collection. To be more precise, a `Map` is a `Set` of keys with values attached to them. Since `Set`s only have distinct elements, and aren't ordered, so are `Map`s.

**SortedMap[String, Int]**

However, there is an implementation of `Map` with sorted keys, and that's `SortedMap`. It uses an implicit `Ordering[Key]` to keep key-value pairs ordered by their key (note that it keeps unicity of keys, so that you cannot have two values for a given key).

For instance

```
SortedMap(-1 -> "neg", 1 -> "pos") + (0 -> "zero") ==
  SortedMap(-1 -> "neg", 0 -> "zero", 1 -> "pos")
```

However, in your case, it might be difficult to keep an implicit `Ordering[String]` different from the usual one (which is lexicographical order).

**Seq[(String, Int)]**

You might want to convert your `Map[String, Int]` to a `Seq[(String, Int)]`. That way, you can play with the order of your values, but you'll loose the fast lookup for a given key.

If you want to do this, you can specify your order first by using a list of keys in order, and then mapping on it using the original map.

```
val original: Map[String, Int] = Map("d" -> 4, "a" -> 12, "c" -> 30, "b" -> 2)
orderedMap: List[(String, Int)] = for {
    key <- List("d", "b", "a", "c")
    value <- original.get(key)
  } yield key -> value
```

Note that I used `original.get(key)` to avoid the case where one of your keys is not actually defined in the original map.

Now, to get a value for a given key, using this `List[(String, Int)]` type, you have to do

```
def getKey(key: String): Option[Int] = orderedMap.
  find(_._1 == key).  //find the first pair where the first element is the desired key
  map(_._2)  // keep only the value if it exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

`SortedMap.apply` take implicit `Ordering` that define order. For example:

```
implicit val stringReverse = Ordering.String.reverse
val xs = Map("a" -> 3, "b" -> 5)
SortedMap(xs.toList:_*) // Map(b -> 5, a -> 3)
```

[How to define own Ordering](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html)